# show that any two polynomials in $ F[x] $ are congruent modulo a nonzero polynomial $ p(x) $

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification, proof-writing

Is the below proof correct, and is there a more succinct way to prove this?

I just went directly and showed (I think)
 $$(\forall f(x),g(x) \in F[x])( \exists k(x) \in F[x])(f(x)-g(x)=p(x)k(x))$$ where $ p(x)$ is a nonzero constant polynomial in $ F[x]$

**Problem**:

If $p(x)$ is a nonzero constant polynomial in $F[x]$, show that any two polynomials in $F[x]$ are congruent modulo $p(x)$

**Proof**:

Let $f(x),g(x)\in F[x]$ and $p(x)$ be a nonzero constant polynomial in $F[x]$. We wish to show $\exists k(x)\in F[x]$ s.t. $f(x) - g(x) = p(x)k(x)$.
Note, that since $p(x)$ is a nonzero constant polynomial $p(x)=c$ for $c\ne 0_F\in F$. Now, suppose $f(x)-g(x)=ck(x)$. Since $F$ is a field we have the existence of a multiplicative inverse $c^{-1}$. Hence, $k(x)=c^{-1}[f(x)-g(x)]$ and such a $k(x)$ exists as was to be shown.

It's the wording of going from the supposition to showing the existence I'm not sure about. Since semantically speaking haven't I assumed the thing I'm trying to prove at the point of $f(x)-g(x)=ck(x)$? Wasn't sure how to word this intermediary step. Is this valid? My proof techniques are a little rusty.

Comment: It's ok. But you can put it more simpy. Just say that $f - g = c (c^{-1} (f - g))$.